# Expectation of Quantum Heat Bath Exponentials

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, condensed-matter, lie-algebra, open-quantum-systems

**Background**

I am studying the paper Lee et al (2012), located at [arXiv:1207.7174](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.7174). In this paper, we study the spin-boson model under a polaron transformation. The Hamiltonian is $$H = \frac{\epsilon}{2}\sigma_z + \frac{\Delta}{2}\sigma_x + \sum_k\omega_k b_k^{\dagger}b_k + \sigma_z\sum_k \omega_k (b_k^{\dagger}-b_k)$$ and the polaron operator is defined by $$F = \sigma_z\sum_k\frac{g_k}{\omega_k}(b_k^{\dagger}-b_k).$$

**Problem**

I've derived the transformed Hamiltonian $H' = e^FHe^{-F}$ without difficulty. However, I am having trouble calculating Eq. 6 in the paper, which defined the expectation of the bath operators $$D_{\pm} = \exp\left[\pm\sum_k \frac{g_k}{\omega_k}(b_k^{\dagger}-b_k)\right]$$ as $R = \langle D_{\pm}^2\rangle_{H_B},$ where $H_B = \sum_k \omega_kb_k^{\dagger}b_k$. If we introduce the spectral density $$J(\omega) = \pi\sum_kg_k^2\delta(\omega-\omega_k),$$ the paper claims we can write $R$ as $$R = \exp\left[-2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{d\omega}{\pi}\frac{J(\omega)}{\omega^2}\coth(\beta\omega/2)\right].$$

**Attempted Solution**

For simplicity, I temporarily write $D_+ = e^C$, where $C = \sum_k\frac{g_k}{\omega_k}(b_k^{\dagger}-b_k)$. Then, I can write $R$ as $$R = \langle D_+^2\rangle_{H_B} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\langle C^n\rangle_{H_B},$$ which reduced the problem to calculating the moments of C. However, at this point I am unsure how to proceed. Any help given would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if you have $A$ an operator which is linear in bosonic operators, and you want to calculate its expectation value when the bosons are non-interacting, then
$$ \langle e^A \rangle = \exp\left[\langle A \rangle + \frac{1}{2}\left(\langle A^2 \rangle-\langle A \rangle^2\right) \right]$$
which is a consequence of Wick's theorem.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a reference where I can see the full calculation? I’m still uncomfortable using Wick’s theorem.

Comment: googling, I found this: https://www.imperial.ac.uk/media/imperial-college/research-centres-and-groups/theoretical-physics/msc/current/qft/problem-sheets-and-solutions/qftProblemSheet1Answers.pdf (section 4). However, thinking about it you don't even need Wick's theorem: each mode $b_k$ is independent, and what you have is a coherent state (using the displacement operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_operator) and the matrix elements in this specific case can be calculated.